# Is it possible to terminal login remotely (outside local network) to my mac at home via SSH + VPN?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop

With [image], I can access my mac at home via VNC.
When in the same network, I also can access it via ssh with the name NAME.local with the help of bonjour.

[image]

Then, is it possible to terminal login the mac at home via VNC + SSH or anything? I tried with NAME.local outside local network, but the name is not recognized.

### ADDED

```
ssh computername.`echo show Setup:/Network/BackToMyMac | scutil | sed -n 's/.* : *\(.*\).$/\1/p'`
```

also works fine.

Reference: http://smithjw.me/blog/2012/8/1/initiating-screen-sharing-or-back-to-my-mac-from-the-command.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the iCloud Back to My Mac address to SSH/VNC in. You can obtain your address using the following command.

```
dns-sd -E
```

The final line shows the account number.
Use the following syntax for determining the address:

```
computername.number.members.btmm.icloud.com
```

Providing you have port forwarded correctly, you can use this address to connect over SSH/VNC.

Comment: I updated the post, could you help me out?

Comment: @prosseek Make sure your computer name is correct — run `hostname` and use that as your computer name.

Comment: I tried the name from `host`, but I got the same error. The name includes .local, I tried with and without it to get the same error.

Comment: @prosseek Try setting the hostname to not include .local — run `scutil --set HostName yourcomputername`

Comment: Well, I tried scutil, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @prosseek Interesting, it should work I think. Do you have a firewall enabled? Stealth mode in System Preferences?

Comment: Well, not that I aware of; I just didn't set anything more than from the default setting. VNC (Screen sharing) works fine.

Comment: ping doesn't work, but ssh does work: http://smithjw.me/blog/2012/8/1/initiating-screen-sharing-or-back-to-my-mac-from-the-command.html